# Fallback Overkill?

Tags: php, optimization, error-handling, fallback

I have had no formal teaching in coding and was hoping if anyone could tell me if I was being to cautious with my code?

```
// Insert info to the db
if ($stmt = $db_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO db (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    if(!$stmt->execute([$val1, $val2])) {
        exit("1:Faild to create deal");
    }
    // Get last id
    $id = (int)$db_connect->lastInsertId();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
} else { exit("0:Faild to create deal"); }

// Create the folder
if(!mkdir("folder/folder".$id)) {
    if($stmt = $db_connect->prepare("DELETE FROM db WHERE id=?")) {
        if(!$stmt->execute([$id])) {
            exit("1:Faild to create the directory -> Faild to remove the row from the database");
        }
        exit("Faild to create the directory");
    }
    exit("0:Faild to create the directory -> Faild to remove the row from the database");
}
```

I repeat the create folder statement 2 more times with the same layout. It's just repeatable code that looks to be overkill.

Note: The package I have with my host only has MyISAM tables so I can't use Rollback.

If something fails I want to undo everything that has passed.

Could someone please give me some guidance to best practices or am I doing it right?

Comment: well, it would help if you would explain in your question what exactly you are trying to do. you are first inserting a row into your db - then you check if you can create a folder. and if you can't create it you delete the exact same row again? why don't you check if you can create the folder at first - and if not, you don't even insert anything into your db ?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did. Its not the what I am doing it's more the how I am doing it that I wanted help with. Your suggestion works both ways. If I can create the directory but then can't update the database I still have to delete the directory

Comment: I should have been more clear at the fact that if something fails I want to undo everything that has passed

Comment: but it's more common that there is a problem with creating the folder than that there are problems with your database. plus, deleting your folder will have no visual influence on your system, while inserting and deleting in your database has: unused numbers, when you use `auto increment` ids

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! While this post has been up I have been fiddling around with my code and I think by rearranging the order I should be able to reduce it quite a bit. Thanks for the input! I will add an update once I'm done and see if there is anything else that could be improved

Comment: maybe wait a bit, i am currently working on an answer ;)

Comment: oh wait, i just found out, that you will need your `lastInsertId()` to be able to create a unique folder !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60790/discussion-between-christopherstrydom-and-northkildonan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i re-structured and extended your code plus added a bit of simple error handling by using exceptions.
first you should set your `PDO` error handling to exception mode:

```
$db_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

then i have capsulated your actions into functions, which you can put into a separate file and include it, or even nest them into classes:

```
/*** FUNCTIONS ***/
// insert info to the db
function dbInsertInfo($db_connect, $val1, $val2)
{
    $stmt = $db_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO db (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute([$val1, $val2]));
}
//-------------------------------

// get the last insert id
function dbGetId($db_connect)
{
    $id = (int)$db_connect->lastInsertId();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return $id;
}
//-------------------------------

// delete db-entry
function dbDeleteId($db_connect, $id)
{
    $stmt = $db_connect->prepare("DELETE FROM db WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
}
//-------------------------------

// create the folder
function createFolder($id)
{
    if(!mkdir("folder/folder".$id)) throw new Exception("Failed to create the directory");
}
//-------------------------------
```

then here is your procedure with all the `try{ } catch{ }` sections for the error handling by exceptions:

```
/* PROCEDURE */

// 01 | try to insert into db
try 
{
    dbInsertInfo($db_connect, $val1, $val2);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //if exception thrown, do not continue the script:
    echo "Unable to insert into DB: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
//-------------------------------

// 02 | try to get last insert id
$id = false;
try 
{
    $id = dbGetId($db_connect);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //if exception thrown, do not continue the script:
    echo "Unable to get last insert id from DB: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
//-------------------------------

// 03 | try to create folder // if it fails -> try to delete db entry
try 
{
    createFolder($id);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // if exception caught, try to remove the corresponding DB entry:
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "<br />";
    echo "trying to remove DB entry now";

    // try to delete db entry
    try
    {
        dbDeleteId($db_connect, $id);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        //if exception thrown, do not continue the script:
        echo "Unable to delete from DB: ".$e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
//-------------------------------
/* Everything worked fine if you get to this point of the code*/
```

just might seem like an technical overkill for you now, but i think it's much more structured and better to read it, once you got into it. plus, it's only divided into 3 steps.

Comment: there might be on issue with `$id = dbGetId();` being inside the `try{}` and thus being not accessible elswhere.. hang on.

Comment: ok, it seems it doesn't matter - but i will update the answer and define `$id` on the outside first to be sure.

Comment: Thanks! I have never used exceptions before... Think I will do some reading on the subject

Comment: you are welcome. `PDO` is throwing its own exceptions which is quite handy. plus, their message also is very informative and you can decide by yourself if you want to `echo` em or not. in my classes i never output them, i just write them to an error-log file.

Comment: oh, there are more issues. you also need to add your db-handler to the parameters of every function using it. i'll change this tomorrow in my answer.

Comment: Yea PDO is very handy. It's okay I got the just of it, I know that you need to include the DB handler in a function and what not. Thank again for all your input